# Why I don't get zero option when I apply even/odd check?

Tags: python, list

When I apply `even`, `odd`, and `zero` checking on a list of numbers, it works well, but for `zero` I get `EVEN Number` instead of `Zero Number`. Where is my mistake?

```
class COPY:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.n = number

    def even_odd_zero(self):
        x = []
        for i in self.n:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                x.append('EVEN Number')
            elif i % 2 != 0:
                x.append('ODD Number')
            else:
                x.append('Zero Number')

        return x



nnn = COPY([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
print(nnn.even_odd_zero())
```

The results:

```py
[
    'ODD Number',
    'EVEN Number',
    'ODD Number',
    'EVEN Number',
    'ODD Number',
    'EVEN Number',
    'ODD Number',
    'EVEN Number',
    'ODD Number',
    'EVEN Number'
]
```

Comment: What's `0 % 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0 is an even number.  If you want special handling for that case, put it first in your `if/elif/else` chain

Answer (score 3):

`i % 2` is either `0`, or not `0`, so the `else` block will never be executed.

```
if i % 2 == 0:
    x.append('EVEN Number')
elif i % 2 != 0:
    x.append('ODD Number')
# Unreachable code below
else:
    x.append('Zero Number')
```

If you want something to be added to `x` when `i` is `0` you could do:

```
if i == 0:
    x.append('Zero Number')
elif i % 2 == 0:
    x.append('EVEN Number')
elif i % 2 != 0:
    x.append('ODD Number')
```

Answer (score 2):

your problem lies in the fact that *0 modulus 2*, or *0 % 2 = 0*.
A working example would be

```
class COPY:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.n = number

    def even_odd_zero(self):
        x=[]
        for i in self.n:
            # check if i is zero
            if i == 0:
                x.append("Zero Number")
            elif i % 2 == 0:
                x.append("Even Number")
            elif i% 2 != 0:
                x.append("Odd Number")
        return x
numberList = COPY([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
print(numberList.even_odd_zero())
```

Result:

```
['Zero Number',
 'Odd Number',
 'Even Number',
 'Odd Number',
 'Even Number',
 'Odd Number',
 'Even Number',
 'Odd Number',
 'Even Number',
 'Odd Number']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, dear.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing in this is that the code is executed line by line so
if you enter the

a = int(input("Enter the first Number :"))

if a == 0:

print(a, "Entered number is zero")

elif a % 2 == 0:

```
print(a, "is even number")
```

elif a % 2 != 0:

```
print(a, "is zero")
```

else:

```
print("Placed")
```

a == 0 in if statement then its shows that it is zero.